# More shortcuts while editing! Wanted: \$(\$) enter math here \$(\$)-Shortcut

Tags: support, feature-request, editing, user-interface

By chance I realized that there are shortcuts in the Question/Answer fields. To my disappointment some useful ones are missing:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+$X_1$

```
$ enter math here $
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+$X_2$

```
$$ enter equation here $$
```

---

**UPDATE**

I just found this script

https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons

Works fine:

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+m gives`$ $`
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+d gives `$$ $$`

---

Here is my current list:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+q

> Blockquote

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+k

`enter preformatted text here`

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+r

---

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+u

- List item

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+i

*emphasized text*

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+o

1. List item

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+g

[image]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+h

### Heading

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+l

[image]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+b

**strong text**

They don't work in comments, but

> Are there more?

Comment: As far as I can tell, stackoverflow.com is rather hostile towards comments being substantial; I expect it to be very difficult to persuade them to make changes to assist in writing substantial comments.

Comment: @Hurkyl, Oh I don't care about the comments, I thought about a shortcuts for inserting `$ $` and `$$ $$`...

Comment: I often use `undo` and `redo` (CTRL+Z and CTRL+SHIFT+Z).

Comment: Btw. I've recently seen somebody using `>! This semantics for a spoiler`. I don't know if it is documented anywhere - at least it is very rarely used.

Comment: @savick01 I'm sorry, but that's syntax. :)

Comment: @Lord_Farin Sorry, to late for edit:( Always mixing up the two:/

Comment: @savick01 see here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers

Comment: I'd think this kind of shortcut would be as useful to this site as the code formatting shortcut is to our programming sites. A thought, though - rather than having two separate shortcut keys, it may be simpler to have a single key that just checks context. Like how our code formatting shortcut works, it'll use the correct syntax based on whether you're writing it inline or as a block. We could do the same to handle the nuances between `$` and `$$`.

Comment: @GraceNote Because the double dollar sign can also be used in an "inline" fashion, it may be simpler just to let pressing the single dollar sign twice have the desired effect.